# Multiple foreach loops inside each other

Tags: php, html

I'm trying to do multiple foreach loops inside each other and stop at 12, this is what I have so far which isn't working. It shows exactly how I want it to. However, each file is supposed to loop through but it's showing image 1 over and over again for the first image in each directory.

```
<?php
date_default_timezone_set('Europe/London');
$dirname = "dir1";
$dirnameTwo = "dir2";
$dirnameThree = "dir3";

$cam1 = scandir($dirname, 1);
$cam2 = scandir($dirnameTwo, 1);
$cam3 = scandir($dirnameThree, 1);
?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC '-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN' 'http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd'>

<head>
    <meta http-equiv='refresh' content='10'>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <meta http-equiv='cache-control' content='max-age=0' />
    <meta http-equiv='cache-control' content='no-cache' />
    <meta http-equiv='expires' content='0' />
    <meta http-equiv='expires' content='Tue, 01 Jan 1980 1:00:00 GMT' />
    <meta http-equiv='pragma' content='no-cache' />
</head>
<html>

<body>
<style type="text/css">
    .pi-title {
        padding: 1rem;
    }
</style>
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="pi-title">
            <h3>Test</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="table-container col-md-12">
            <table class="table" border='1' cellpadding='5' cellspacing='0' bordercolor='#ccc'>
                <thead class="thead-dark">
                <tr>
                    <th scope="col">ID</th>
                    <th scope="col">File Name</th>
                    <th scope="col">PI 1</th>
                    <th scope="col">PI 2</th>
                    <th scope="col">PI 3</th>
                </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                <tr></tr>
                <tr>
                    <?php
                    array_multisort(array_map('filectime', ($files = glob("*.*", GLOB_BRACE))), SORT_DESC, $files);
                    $dirs = array($dirname, $dirnameTwo, $dirnameThree);
                    $comma_separated = implode(",", $dirs);
                    $i = 1;
                    foreach ($cam1 as $cams1) {
                        foreach ($cam2 as $cams2) {
                            foreach ($cam3 as $cams3) {
                                foreach ($files as $filename) {
                                    if (file_exists($filename)) {
                                        echo "</tr>";
                                        echo "<td><font face='Arial' size='6'>$i</font></td>";
                                        echo "<td><font face='Arial' size='6' color='red'>" . date("F d Y H:i", filemtime($filename));
                                        echo "</font></td>";
                                    }
                                    print("

                                               <td><img src='$dirs[0]/$cams1' height='180' width='220'></td>
                                               <td><img src='$dirs[1]/$cams2' height='180' width='220'></td>
                                               <td><img src='$dirs[2]/$cams3' height='180' width='220'></td>

                           ");
                                    $i++;
                                    if ($i == 13) break;
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    ?>
                </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The loops keep on going past 12 and only shows the 1st file in each directory over and over again without getting each file in each directory.

Comment: Did you want to use `if ($i == 13) break 4;` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure what you're trying to do - you haven't given any example input and output, and your code is written in a very unclear style - but there's a number of things that look wrong to me.

---

Firstly, your innermost loop is not related to the other three in any way:

```
foreach ($files as $filename)
```

You define `$files` once, buried in the middle of this ugly line:

```
array_multisort(array_map('filectime', ($files = glob("*.*", GLOB_BRACE))), SORT_DESC, $files);
```

So the innermost loop is going to look at the same list of files over and over again.

This also means that this line is redundant:

```
if (file_exists($filename))
```

Unless the file was deleted in the microseconds since PHP ran the `glob` command, this will always be true, because `$files` is populated with files that exist.

---

Secondly, your nested loops will end up going through not just every item from each directory, but every possible combination. Consider the following miniature example:

```
$cam1 = ['a', 'b'];
$cam2 = ['c', 'd'];
$cam3 = ['e', 'f'];
$files = ['g', 'h'];
foreach ($cam1 as $cams1) {
     foreach ($cam2 as $cams2) {
          foreach ($cam3 as $cams3) {
              foreach ($files as $filename) {
                   echo "$cams1, $cams2, $cams3, $filename \n";
              }
          }
     }
}
```

Outputs:

```
a, c, e, g 
a, c, e, h 
a, c, f, g 
a, c, f, h 
a, d, e, g 
a, d, e, h 
a, d, f, g 
a, d, f, h 
b, c, e, g 
b, c, e, h 
b, c, f, g 
b, c, f, h 
b, d, e, g 
b, d, e, h 
b, d, f, g 
b, d, f, h
```

It's hard to tell if that's what you intended.

---

Thirdly, [a `break` statement](http://php.net/break) only breaks out of *one* loop, unless you give it an argument. So this line will break out of the `foreach($files as $filename)` loop:

```
if ($i == 13) break;
```

To break out of *all* the loops, you need to name how many to break out of:

```
if ($i == 13) break 4;
```

Comment: Also the html. `<head>` html element should be inside `<html>`. And there's this sequence `</tr><td>`. `<td>` elements should be inside `<tr>`.

Comment: Perfect, this fixed my issue.